# Change title when tablix more than on 1 page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I need change title in header when tablix more than on 1 page on PDF format. For example on 2..n page I need show 'Car - Continued' instead of 'Car'. SSRS 2008.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the expression for the title using the `IIF`

```
 =IIF(Globals!PageNumber =1,"Your Title","Your title continued")
```

More info on the Expression of [SSRS are here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx).3

---

**Update**

Now as I understand you want to reset the page number for each table 
so here are the three steps to achieve what you want,

1) Select `Tablix` and open the properties window

2) Set the `Break Location' to`End`

3) Set the `ResetPageNumber` to the `True`

and do this for each table except the last one .

Here is the image showing the details

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry, I forgot to specify that a lot of tables on the PDF report. So, table 'Car' may start on the first page, but the second table, for example 'Bike' may start on the 5th page. And it is dynamic value because   dependen on valume table 'Car'. And If 'Bike' start on the 5th page, on the 6th page I should write 'Bike - Continued'.  So, this expression I can't use.

Comment: I have updated the answer. If it helps you please accept it as answer. So the question can be closed.